# Is there concept of continuous curve and surfaces in p-adic field?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

Is there any concept of continuity in p-adic field (field of p-adic numbers) ?

Is there concept of continuous curve and surfaces in p-adic field?

**Answer:**

I know that the field of p-adic numbers is totally disconnected.

So question of continuous curves and surface or cncept of continuity , differentiability does not arise.

But I am not getting confidence .

Can someone give me more details about the above questions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The $p$-adic field comes with a metric, thus you have the concept of continuity (continuous curves). I don't quite see, why being totally disconnected should prevent myself from studying continuous maps. I think you confuse the notion of being totally disconnected with carrying the discrete topology (where all maps are continuous). You can (for example) easily see that not all maps from the rationals are continuous (e.g. take the sign function).

Comment: I am afraid, I am not an expert in non-archimedian analysis. My knowledge on that topic is (at best) basic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The $p$-adic numbers are a metric space, and thus a topological space. Therefore continuity is well defined, either by the $\varepsilon,\delta$ definition that you know from Calculus, or by the simpler-looking criterion that if $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces, then $f:X\to Y$ is continuous if and only if for every open subset $U\subset Y$, the set $f^{-1}(U)$ is an open subset of $X$.

To define a curve in the $p$-adic concept, you have to know what you’re looking for, know what the definition ought to be. You may look at a $2$-variable polynomial $F(X,Y)$ with $\Bbb Q_p$-coefficients, and ask for all $(a,b)\in\Bbb Q_p\times\Bbb Q_p$ such that $F(a,b)=0$. This is the outlook (suitably generalized and jazzed up) that is taken in Algebraic Geometry. Just as, for instance $Y^2-X^2(X-1)^2$ gives you a nice curve in $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$, so the same polynomial, having integer coefficients, makes perfectly good $p$-adic sense, though I don’t think that anyone would say that the $p$-adic curve looked like a butterfly.

Or you may think of a curve as parametrized: in the familiar real context, you might take a continuous map of the closed unit interval into $\Bbb R^2$ and ask for the form of the image (“range”) of this map. Similarly, taking the analog of the unit interval to be the subset $\Bbb Z_p$ of $p$-adic numbers within $\Bbb Q_p$, you might ask for continuous maps of $\Bbb Z_p$ into $\Bbb Q_p^2$.

What you ought never do, is try for continuous maps of $[0,1]$ into $\Bbb Q_p^2$: as you know, the latter is totally disconnected, so that the only maps to it from a connected set like $[0,1]$ will be constant.

In the $p$-adic world, it is perfectly possible to define differentiability and ask about the derivative of a function. Total disconnectedness offers no impediment whatever. Notice, by the way, that although there are no interesting continuous maps from the reals to the $p$-adics, there are plenty in the opposite direction. Indeed, the $p$-adic absolute-value function is just one such.

What’s the moral of my sermon? That there are far more interesting analytic and geometric phenomena in the $p$-adic world than you assumed. It is true, however, that the flavor of these is very different from what you know from the Archimedean world.

Comment: A lot of thanks Sir. You just gave the nicest explanation .

Comment: With all due respect, I find the statement "Total disconnectedness offers no impediment whatever" slightly exaggerated. Surely one has a nice theory of continuous and differentiable maps, but if I recall correctly (from Schikhof's *Ultrametric Calculus* years ago) some things feel outrageous ("wild" functions with derivative 0, everything can be approximated by locally constant functions etc.). Also, I vaguely remember people saying the reason why *locally analytic* manifolds, as opposed to differentiable or continuous ones, are the interesting objects in $p$-adics, is related to that.

Comment: Note that your example of a curve is polynomial/algebraic $\subseteq$ analytic, which is a much more specific and restricted setting than some general differentiable or even just continuous function (or its graph or range etc.).

Comment: All you say is true, @TorstenSchoeneberg. I didn’t even mention analytic geometry, feeling that a sketchy and potentially inaccurate account was what was called for. Also said nothing about the (to me) strange role that integration plays in all of this, so very different from in the connected case.